# Returning a list with async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Here are two methods,both returning a list of strings:

```
private async Task<List<string>> Lista()
{
    var _folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await _folder.GetFileAsync("MyList.log");
    var read = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

    string[] lines = read.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return lines.ToList();
}

private List<string> GetLog()
{
    var list = new List<string>
    {
        "Test1",
        "Test2",
        "Test3"
    };

    return list;
}
```

My goal here is to assign my DataContext with the list returned from the method Lista().
For some reason it does not work. With not work I mean that nothing gets passed to the XAML-view.

when I set DataContext = GetLog() everything works fine. But when I set DataContext = Lista() it does not work.

Im new to working with asyn method, maybe im missing something?

But as far as I can tell both methods returns a list of strings so they both should work?

Complete code:

```
public Loggar()
        {

            this.DataContext = await Lista();
        }



        private async Task<List<string>> Lista()
        {
            var _folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var file = await _folder.GetFileAsync("MyListenerVerbose.log");
            var read = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

            string[] lines = read.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            return lines.ToList();
        }
```

The problem is here:

```
this.DataContext = await Lista();
```

The word `await` has a red line it and the intellisense says the same as I wrote in the first comment, am i missing something else?

Comment: DataContext= **await** Lista()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot write a `async` constructor.

You can call a non-await async method from constructor, like:

```
public SomePage() { setDataContext(); }

async void setDataContext() { DataContext = await Lista(); }
```

(`async void` means this method will run in background but will return to caller immediately, the caller don't need to wait for it)

Or you can call the async method sync, **But it will block your UI!**

```
public SomePage() { DataContext = Lista().Result; }
```

(Uses `Task<T>.Result` will wait for the method done and then returns its result.)

A method returns `Task<T>` can use `await` keyword to get its `Result`. If you mark your method as `async`, compiler will build a special helper class to get every `Result` on another thread, so it will not block your UI.

(So any `async` method is a `class`, in fact, but the compiler will get everything done to make it looks like a method to you.)

But you cannot do it on constructors, constructors must return value (the new object) in sync.

(or you can say constructors must be methods but not classes.)

Comment: Thank you both, I ended up ptting this line of code in the method:
DataContext = lines.ToList();

Seemed like the ctor was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

`Lista` doesn't return a `List<string>` it returns a `Task<List<string>>`.  You can't get the list of strings until the task is completed.

You should `await` the task returned from `Lista`, which will return the resulting `List`.

Comment: Thank you, tried this in the Page constructor:
this.DataContext = await Lista();
Intellisense says that the "await"-operator only can be used in a method with the async keyword..

Comment: @DirkWrangler And it is exactly right in its analysis.

Comment: Im sure it is but how can I then take care of the result(the list of strings) and assign the list to datacontext?

Comment: @DirkWrangler You `await` it from an `async` method, exactly as you've been told.

Comment: And this is not the correct way?:
this.DataContext = await Lista();
Im sorry but i do not understand

Comment: @DirkWrangler You need to do exactly what the error message is telling you to do.  It's crystal clear on what you need to do in order to use `await`, and you're doing the same thing in the method `Lista`.

Comment: @DirkWrangler: You can't use `await` from a constructor. To solve this, you'll need to first initialize the view model to a "loading" state and then update it later to the "loaded" state. I describe a few approaches [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: Its not so crystal clear to me. You say that this.DataContext = await Lista() is the right way to do it but it does not work. I really have no idea what to try?